# How secure is UltraVNC?

Tags: remote-desktop, rc4, vnc

I've found that [UltraVNC Single Click](https://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-sc.html) is an interesting alternative to TeamViewer. 
However it as far I understand uses RC4 to encrypt. Would you recommend this tool to remote desktop bearing in mind the security?

Comment: RC4 is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked on the link you provided and got this:
[image: error reported by uvnc]

It doesn't inspire a lot of confidence - this error usually means that the server is only offering ancient ciphersuites. But there are several people offering VNC server and client implementations. I am currently using tigervnc.

The reason I went to have a look at the uvnc site is that there are a lot of different ways to expose a VNC service. You could use the SSL support [within the application](https://linuxtechlab.com/secure-vnc-server-tls-encryption/), via a seperate VPN, ssh or [SSL tunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/).

Personally, I'm [using novnc to expose the VNC service in a web page](https://symcbean.blogspot.com/2020/03/covid19-provisioning-remote-access-with.html) - which avoids having to install a VNC client wherever I want to connect from and uses the protocols/ciphers available in openssl.